# Create subnet without Internet access

Tags: internet, network

I want to create a subnet in our network, where the devices which will be connected in this subnet (e.g. 192.168.20.x) will not have access in the Internet.

However, these devices will be accessible from other subnets (e.g. fro 192.168.0.x)

The router is [D-LINK DSR-1000AC](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dsr-1000ac-wireless-ac-unified-services-vpn-router) and the switch [D-LINK DGS-1210](http://us.dlink.com/products/business-solutions/dgs-1210-52mp/)

Is it possible to create such a network?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, D-Link doesn't offer a paid support option for its products, so they are off-topic here.It should be possible as long as the router support multiple local networks (not all SOHO router does it), using a firewall policy to block traffic from 192.168.20.xxx to the Internet.

Comment: With business-grade hardware this would be very easy (create a VLAN/zone and configure routing/filtering appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the switch create 3 VLANs:

The first one, let's call it **VLAN A** for all the devices in range `192.168.20.xxx`.

The second one **VLAN B** for the devices in `192.168.0.xxx`.

And a third one for example **VLAN C** for the router.

**Keep in mind** that you must change the IP address of the router to make it belong to another subnet: `192.168.10.XXX`for example.

**It means also** that the router will be unable to act as DHCP server and the devices on the other two VLANs must get their IP addresses from other DHCP server on their respective VLANs or be configured manually.

---

In the switch there is a feature called *static routing* that you can use to create routes between VLANs.

1. Create an static route from **VLAN A** to **VLAN B**.
2. Another static route from **VLAN B** to **VLAN C**.

In that way *VLAN A* can communicate to *VLAN B*, but will be unable to reach *VLAN C*.